# Why shift button still acting like pressed for a short time when I released?

Tags: keyboard

This weird problem happening mostly on Linux installed Laptops. (Actually I'm not using Windows)

While I'm writing a text quite fast, in case of writing capital letter, pressing shift for typing capital letter and then releasing the key, the shift key acting like still pressed for a half of second. When I check the text I can see words typed like this:

Say, I wrote the text below:

> This Is The Example

It looks like this:

> THis IS THe EXample

Actually this is not happening in that frequent, but very often. Sometimes, I can't login to freshly registered website, because of this problem. It makes me type my password wrong, and this is drives me nuts until I figured out what happened.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me from time to time on Windows too, and I have to admit it's my fault: I'm tired, or just try to type faster then I can.

Issues happening often, but not according to a pattern, and only for half a second are very difficult to reproduce, and honestly I don't think it's an issue with the pc.
Sorry to say, you need to practice typing.

Comment: Your idea is not so wrong, but I'm pretty sure for that problem is exist because I'm experienced many different computers in many years, I'm using computers since 1996. This is not happened some of computers except my faults, but the others. I'm aware when I made mistakes, but the thing is real. Even when I wrote in extreme caution, the event is happening, and not for once.

Comment: If that's related to a computer, can't be it's keyboard. maybe when you need to press buttons on a longer way, then you don't always have enough time to release Shift before pressing the next key?

Comment: I don't think so. As I said, this is happening while I writing in extreme caution. This is not related to my typing skill.

Comment: I can even argue that the beginning of this problem came at the same time as the USB keyboards began to be produced. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too, and my OS is Ubuntu 20.04 running on my laptop. It is a **setting problem**, you can open the *Settings*, and find *Typing Assist*. In the listed settings, you will find "*Sticky Keys*". Everything will be OK after you turn off this setting.